# SignalR + Redis on local computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, signalr

I've downloaded the last Signalr.Redis package (v0.1) and I've compiled the last Redis source code (2.4.26).
I tried to run Redis on my local pc (server and client work well) but when I start SignalR with Redis as a message broadcaster, it seems that signalr wants to start multiple connection to server (same server=localhost but multiple port number).

I know that Redis integration with SignalR is new and perphaps buggy, but is it possible to work with redis+signalr on local machine or is not a supported scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR will attempt to make a variety of connections to the server in order to keep an open connection.  For most browsers it ends up long polling the server (which results in multiple requests regardless).  What I ended up doing was using allowing SignalR to connect in a normal fashion to my MVC app and then call actions on my controllers which in turn communicated with Redis.  This gives me the added benefit of being able to perform business logic in between.  Not sure I answered your question, but I just wanted to share how its worked for me.